How to get the result from Stripe.onPaymentResult in Stripe payment gateway since onActivityResult is deprecated in android?
In stripe payment their is method call confirmPayment where we input with paymentMethodCreateParams and clientSecret. The result of the confirmPayment is triggered in onActivityResult. But onActivityResult is deprecate in android. How to get the Stripe PaymentResult?. Is their any alternative for this problem
private var stripe : Stripe? = null


fun confirmPayment() {
   stripe = Stripe(context = this, publishableKey = publishableKey)
   val paymentMethodCreateParams = PaymentMethodCreateParams.create(myDebitCard)
   val confirmPaymentIntent=ConfirmPaymentIntentParams.createWithPaymentMethodCreateParams(
      paymentMethodCreateParams = paymentMethodCreateParams,
      clientSecret = clientSecret
   )
    stripe?.confirmPayment(this, confirmPaymentIntent) // this means activity or fragment
}

The result of the confirm payment is triggered in
// Deprecate Now
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
stripe?.onPaymentResult(
            requestCode = requestCode,
            data = data,
            callback = object : ApiResultCallback<PaymentIntentResult> {
                override fun onError(e: Exception) {
                    // Handle Error case
                }

                override fun onSuccess(result: PaymentIntentResult) {
                    // Handle Success case
                }

            }
        )
}


If Stripe hasn't written their own custom contract that uses the new Activity Result API, then you have to keep using the deprecated APIs (it also means their API will never work in Jetpack Compose). You probably want to contact them directly to request that they use the now 3 year old APIs.

Overall your integration is somewhat outdated. Stripe's Android SDKs do indeed support Jetpack Compose in integrations where PaymentSheet is presented to collect payment methods information. You shouldn't be handling raw card data (like you seemingly are) without the required PCI compliance.

@JonathanSteele, I am not using Jetpack Compose. I use the code mentioned above in an activity. My app only needs a custom UI for payment-related tasks. Is there an alternative way to get the confirmPayment result?

@SumanRadhakrishnan Follow JonathanSteele's link and you'll see the classic implementation that doesn't use Jetpack Compose.
